# How to make MSBuild CoreClean before copy step?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I have a Class Library Project which contains t4 templates that execute on build. The output .sql files are set to `Content` of the `.csproj` and should be copied on build to the output folder.

I have the following configuration setup on my TeamCity Build Box using MSBuild:

Command line parameters:

```
/p:OutDir=C:\output\DBMigration
/p:Configuration=Release
/p:DebugSymbols=false 
/p:DebugType=None 
/p:DeleteExistingFiles=true 
/t:rebuild 
/verbosity:n
```

The output of this is that the files are copied to the outputdir but are deleted in the `CoreClean` step of the rebuild.

To get around this I can run a Build instead of a rebuild, (ie. `/t:build`).

This will skip the `CoreClean` step, but why is the `CoreClean` called on the output dir after the Copy process has taken place? Should the Delete action not be before the Copy?

And why do I only need to do this step for ClassLibrary type projects, web/windows applications do not seem to have this problem with the rebuild.

Also it appears from the build log that the output directory is never cleaned by `/p:DeleteExistingFiles=true`.

I could do a hack and force a `powershell` script to run to clean the directory before attempting to build, but there must be a supported MSbuild parameter to do this in the absence of the rebuild preforming correctly?

Comment: Rebuild target usually performs Clean and Build in this order, so Clean has CoreClean as a dependency.

I could not find which target handles p:DeleteExistingFiles, so can't really comment why content files are not cleaned.

Would be nice if you can show detailed build log or prepare a sample project which reproduces the problem - it's hard to debug complex msbuild flow without any factual records.